# How to use regex with visual basic 6?

Tags: regex, vb6

How to use regex with visual basic 6 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

google:

```
vb6 regex
```

First result:
[VB6 Regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/vb.html)

Comment: "Google it" gets 3 upvotes? Wow, clearly I spend way too much time on *my* answers...

Comment: @Cody And the reference is bad. In fact the OP asked another question "how to use it?" five minutes later ... OMG

Comment: "Google it" got me here.

Answer (score 0):

this book may help you

http://books.google.com/books?id=yY_EsWFMj-QC&printsec=frontcover&cd=1&source#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: Interestingly, the book you suggest states explicitly that the code samples it provides won't work in Visual Basic 6.